# Unable to connect to docker

Tags: docker

When i am executing docker commands like `docker container ls` or `docker version` in command prompt phasing issue

it says

```
"error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running."
```

How to resolve this issue??

Comment: did you install the docker with root user and trying to run with different user?

Answer (score 0):

check docker server is running or not, try to restart it or kill it from task-manager and start it again.

Answer (score 0):

Which os you are using, You need to check the status of docker that is it active or not.